# Offline security HTML 5 application

Tags: html, security, encryption, offline

I am working for a webdevelopment company and have been put in charge to secure apps or any other content when the app is not connected to the internet, that means standard login protocols over `HTTPS` don't apply.

The company I work for profiles itself in making application for 'on the road' with bad internet connections. For reasons everyone can understand is that the users must be able to 'lock' the application and be able to unlock as well. Preferably with the password they use to login when they are online (they get a secure cookie which authenticates them when online with the webserver).

Now I need someone way to check the password without letting a hacker easily look into a `websql/indexdb/local` storage and just find it there. Storing it as a simple hash is too easily hacked.

I thought of storing it salted but it would be just a matter of time before it is hacked, also thought of hashing part of the password (like last 4 characters) and a salt. That in case it does get rainbowed they only just unlock the application and not have the password.

I can't really seem to find good and/or standardized ways of securing offline `HTML5` apps. But are there like best practices ?

Another question is the security of the data in the offline storage itself so that only the application can read it. I can come up with ways to make the data 'unreadable' but all the ways I can come up with to store records securely I can also come up with a method to hack it. So any advise in this field is welcome as well.

Comment: Store the data in the encrypted form and do not store the password at all - seems like a solution to both of your concerns.

Comment: I need some way to verify the user when opening the application even when the application has no access to internet, so how do I check if the password is correct? Also I need to decrypt the data for use inside application. So the key to decrypt it is known in javascript.

Comment: Ask for password, derive key from password (search for PBKDF2 as a starting point), try to decrypt the locally stored data. If decryption fails, the password is not the correct one.

Comment: Something like that seems possible but I would need to store the key somewhere when logged in (somewhere in javascript, not local storage etc), encrypt the data I receive, when locking the application I throw away the key. When logging in, I try to decrypt some data and check if it works to see if the password is correct?

Comment: PS move your answer from comment to answer, so I can accept it as such.

Answer (score 1):

Like `ovanwijk` suggested: I think only storing the (salted) hash is fair enough. For a user to unlock the screen he/she clear-types in the passphrase, it will be hashed and must match the storage hash. And that can be used to encrypt data. Luckily Stanford came up with a very nice crypto library for JavaScript: http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl

Sadly in the browser there's no secure place a website has access to but no one else. Think about it: if there was a place you could open up Debugging tools and inject some code to access it. Since JS security is a matter of research only there's no standard solution to this problem...